# Evaluation of the series $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^{k+1}\left ( k+1 \right )^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

The following series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^{k+1}\left ( k+1 \right )^2}$$

came up as an intermediate step of calculating an integral. The answer according to Wolfram is $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^{k+1}\left ( k+1 \right )^2}=\ln 2 +\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

Unfortunately , I have no idea how to attack this. Although I have some suspicions that it should be connected to some of the special functions and that we should differentiate. (i.e ${\rm Li}_n$)

Also, that zero index could easily be changed to $1$ since the fist summand is , obviously, zero. Can anyone help me attain the result. Both real analysis and complex analysis are welcomed...

Comment: Hint: rewrite the numerator as $(k+1)-1$ to get two series : the first one is a simple logarithm, the second will be the [dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) (both evaluated at $\dfrac 12$).

Comment: To prove the second one use $\mathrm{Li}_2(z)=-\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z)-\log (1-z) \log (z)+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$ with $z=\frac 12$.

Comment: I am well aware of ${\rm Li}_2(x)$ properties. That will do. Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k x^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2} $$

$$f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k x^{k}}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k+1} = \frac1{1-x} + \frac{\log{(1-x)}}{x}$$

The sum is then

$$f \left ( \frac12 \right ) = \int_0^{1/2} dx \left [\frac1{1-x} + \frac{\log{(1-x)}}{x} \right ] = \log{2} - \operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac12 \right )$$

Use the fact that $\operatorname{Li}_2(1/2) = \pi^2/12 - \log^2{2}/2$ and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks Ron... it was easy after all...

Comment: It is always easy (for me too) after an answer from Ron Gordon ! Welcome to the club !!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Nicely said...